# BlazeMeter/JMeter Issue: JUnit Sampler ClassNotFoundException

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, blazemeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm new to BlazeMeter and JMeter.

1. I created a simple Selenium JUnit Script, it can run in IDE.
2. I then loaded the script into JMeter using JUnitSampler. I run the test in JMeter on my local and it was able to run. Then I uploaded the .jmx file to BlazeMeter and when I try to run it, it would fail.

If I look into the Logs page on BlazeMeter, it complains ClassNotFoundException. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

```
2017-11-23 20:16:47,497 WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.JUnitSampler: ClassNotFoundException:: xxxxxx.SampleLoadTest2
```

And on BlazeMeter Failed Report Summary page, it shows

```
Error Running Test

The test encountered the following fatal error, and could not complete successfully:

Error: r-v3-5a172c6260523 - Session ended without load report data
```

Comment: @user7294900, do u mean add in JMeter or BlazeMeter? Could you elaborate a bit on the process? I'm very new to both tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you most probably didn’t add the required libraries on Blazemeter (selenium jars...)

So ensure you add them and it should work

Comment: Thank you so much! I added selenium related jars and junit jars and it's working fine now!